# Setting number of decimals in dataframe for a calculated value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to set the precision of the mean value in a dataframe, but I get the following error: TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

I set the arrays as dtype=float. It works if I remove "%.2f"%, but gives more decimal points than I want.

Following is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0.030, 0.031, 0.032], [10, 0.153, 0.155, 0.154], [20, 0.393, 0.397, 0.395]]), columns=['Y0','Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], dtype=float)
Xa=df.loc[:,"Y1":]
mean=Xa.mean(axis=1)
df['mean']="%.2f"%mean
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your implementation, `df['mean'] = "%.2f"%mean` causes a `TypeError` because `mean` is [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html), which can't be converted with `"%.2f"%mean`.

  - Use `df['mean'] = mean.round(3)`.
  - Use [`pandas.Series.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html#pandas.Series.round) to round `pandas.Series` to the desired decimal place, and retain a `float` type.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) with `axis=1` to return the mean for all of the rows, and assign the values to a new column.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) to round an entire dataframe (e.g. `Xa.round(3)`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0.030, 0.031, 0.032], [10, 0.153, 0.155, 0.154], [20, 0.393, 0.397, 0.395]]), columns=['Y0', 'Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], dtype=float)

# select the desired columns
Xa = df.loc[:,"Y1":]

# get the column means and round them
Xa['means'] = Xa.mean(axis=1).round(3)

# display(Xa)
      Y1     Y2     Y3  means
0  0.030  0.031  0.032  0.031
1  0.153  0.155  0.154  0.154
2  0.393  0.397  0.395  0.395
```

Comment: This method keeps numbers as floats rather than strings in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using the round function?

mean=round(Xa.mean(axis=1),2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the map function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 0.030, 0.031, 0.032], [10, 0.153, 0.155, 0.154], [20, 0.393, 0.397, 0.395]]), columns=['Y0','Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3'], dtype=float)
Xa=df.loc[:,"Y1":]
mean=Xa.mean(axis=1)
df['mean']=mean.map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x)
df
```

Output:

```
    Y0      Y1      Y2      Y3      mean
0   0.0     0.030   0.031   0.032   0.03
1   10.0    0.153   0.155   0.154   0.15
2   20.0    0.393   0.397   0.395   0.40
```

Answer (score 1):

`"%.2f"%` works on variables that *are* floats, not variables that *contain* floats. If you want to apply a function to the *contents* of an iterable, rather than the iterable itself, there are several options.

`apply`: 
`mean.apply(lambda x: "%.2f"%x)`

List comprehension: 
`["%.2f"%x for x in mean]` (this turns it into a list).

`map`:
 `df['mean']=mean.map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x)` cf. Kaushal Sharma's answer

Panda's built-in rounding function: 
`mean=round(Xa.mean(axis=1),2)` cf. LevB's answer.

BTW, there's no need to put the numbers into a numpy array before turning it into a dataframe.

Comment: Works great. I removed the unnecessary numpy array part, and then used df['mean']=mean.map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x). This method seems most general, since I can now use other presentation types for floating point and decimal values such as '%.2g'.

Comment: Round by LevB is the Python built-in function https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: @Qwynes except for round and my solution below, these are string formatting options, which mean's your values are now strings, and not floats / numeric.

Comment: If I type print(mean), then I is shows dtype: float64. Are these values not floats anymore? @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: @Qwynes Not after using an `f` format. `print(type(mean[0]))`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Sorry, I am still not following. If I type `print(type(mean[0]))`  the I get the following `<class 'numpy.float64'>`. Does that not signify float?

Comment: @Qwynes Which method did you use to format the column and did you save it? If you do `mean = mean.apply(lambda x: "%.2f"%x)` then you will have string formatted the data. If you only do `mean.apply(lambda x: "%.2f"%x)` then you did not actually save the formatting.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney OK, I think I understand. I only did `mean=Xa.mean(axis=1)` then I used `df['mean']=mean.map(lambda x: '%.2f' % x)` to put in the dataframe`. But if I type `mean`, I get the values as if `'%.2f' %` was not used, so I did not change the formatting of these numbers, just how they are seen in the dataframe.

Comment: @Qwynes In that case, type `print(type(df.loc[0, 'mean']))` to print to check the first value in the `mean` column of `df`.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Now I see `<class 'str'>` for the data in the dataframe as you noted. Thanks for working out with me.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the last bit of your code with the below, it works:

```
df['mean']=['%.2f'%row for row in mean]
```